# How to add title to axes with chartjs on Symfony UX

Tags: symfony, chart.js

I made a chart with Symfony UX and chartJS. All work but i'm battling with the customization.

Has someone succeed to add titles to axes on a chart with chartjs with Symfony UX. I'm trying differents options but I don't know why the title for yAxes and xAxes don't work.

Here is my code :

```
$chart->setOptions([
                'responsive' => true,
                'legend' => ['display' => false],
                'title' => [
                    'display' => true,
                    'text' => 'Title of the graph',
                    'fontSize' => 16
                ],
                'scales' => [
                     'yAxes' => [
                         'title' => [
                             'display'  => true,
                             'text'     => 'Title for y Axes',
                         ]
                     ],

                ],
            ]);
```

The code for the title works perfectly but the title for yAxes do not work.

Has anyone solve this ?

Comment: Which version of chart.js are you using because in V3 the syntax has changed: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Comment: Apparently I use "chart.js": "^2.9.4" according to my package.json